# Quanteda Corpus error while running Ubuntu on WSL2 - Summary function

Tags: r, wsl-2, quanteda

Any idea why I'm getting this error while using summary function:

`quanteda::data_corpus_inaugural %>% summary()`

`Error in if (...length() && any(...names() == "Dimnames")) .Object@Dimnames <- fixupDN(.Object@Dimnames) :   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I'm also getting error while trying to build a DFM, but I believe the one above is simpler to reproduce. The *token* and *corpus* functions seems to be working normaly.

It might be something with my env, but can't figure out what is it. I'm running **Ubuntu** under Win11 (**WSL 2**). Tried even outside RStudio and got same error.

`$ cat /etc/os-release`

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"

NAME="Ubuntu"

VERSION_ID="22.04"

VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

VERSION_CODENAME=jammy

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"

SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"

UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

- R version : 4.1.2
- Packages: **Quanteda 3.2.4 ,** Matrix 1.5-4

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows 11, R 4.2.2, quanteda 3.2.4

Comment: Suspect that it'd be related to the issue I reported here: https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/2214 You can try other versions of Matrix. The latest version of Matrix (which you are using) seems to have fixed the problem, but maybe not.

Comment: Update everything and it should run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@ken-benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158274/ken-benoit) mentioned, upgraded **R** to **4.2.3**, **quanteda** to **3.3.0** and all is running again. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. I updated R (I did not do any thing in R studio).
Now it is OK

(NOTE: I did not do any thing in R studio. I removed R and re installed newest version).